# How can I search through my boklista for a certain keyword?

Tags: c#, list

1. How would I search through boklista with a certain keyword?
   More on this in SökBok().
2. Is the placement of static void Main odd in relation to static class Bibliotekarie?
   Should these be seperated?

I am basically asked to make a library.
One that has a librarian that can add books, with underclasses, uses polymorphism and encapsulation (hence why the list is set to private).
Any suggestions or thoughts would be very much appreciated in advanced.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace bibliotekarie
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string BookNamn;
        public string Author;
        public string BookType;


        public Book(string _BookNamn, String _Author, string _BookType)
        {
            BookNamn = _BookNamn;
            Author = _Author;
            BookType = _BookType;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n\t\t" + BookNamn + " (" + BookType + ")"
            + "\n\t\tby " + Author;
        }

        public virtual string Text()
        {
            return "\t\tFound in section A.";
        }
    }

    public class Novel : Book
    {
        public Novel(string _BookNamn, String _Author, string _BookType) : base(_BookNamn, _Author, _BookType)
        {
            this.BookType = "Novel";
        }

        public override string Text()
        {
            return "\t\tFound in section B.";
        }
    }

    public class ShortStory : Book
    {
        public ShortStory(string _BookNamn, String _Author, string _BookType) : base(_BookNamn, _Author, _BookType)
        {
            this.BookType = "ShortStory";
        }

        public override string Text()
        {
            return "\t\tFound in section C.";
        }
    }

    public class Journal : Book
    {
        public Journal(string _BookNamn, String _Author, string _BookType) : base(_BookNamn, _Author, _BookType)
        {
            this.BookType = "Journal";
        }

        public override string Text()
        {
            return "\t\tFound in section D.";
        }
    }

    static class Librarian
    {

        private static List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();

        public static void GetBookList()
        {
            foreach (Book item in bookList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString() + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine(item.Text() + "\n");
            }
        }
        public static void CreateBook()
        {
            string name = "";
            string author = "";

            while (name.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\tStart by entering the name of the book. Please enter the name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (author.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\tWho is the author of the book?: ");
                author = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n\t\tPlease specify the book type: [1] Novel, [2] Journal, or [3] Short story?: ");
            int nyVal;
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nyVal);

            switch (nyVal)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Book newBok = new Novel(name, author, "(Novel)");
                        bookList.Add(newBok);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tSaved!");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        Book newBok = new Journal(name, author, "(Journal)");
                        bookList.Add(newBok);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tSaved!");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Book newBok = new ShortStory(name, author, "(Short story)");
                        bookList.Add(newBok);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tSaved!");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tNågonting gick fel. Det gick inte att spara. Testa igen.");
                        Console.ResetColor();

                        break;
                    }
            }


        }
        public static void SearchBook()
        {
            string searchItems;
            bool found = false;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\tSearch the library: ");
                searchItems = Console.ReadLine();
                if (searchItems == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tThe search field cannot be empty. Try again!\n");
                }
            } while (searchItems == "");


            // this is what I added
            // for each bok in list
            foreach (var bok in bookList)
            {

                // if bok text matches searchItems
                //if(bok.Text() == searchItems) {   // commented out exact match, to get similar matches using Contains
                if (bok.Text().ToLower().Contains(searchItems.ToLower()))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t" + searchItems + " was found.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t" + searchItems + " was not found.");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bookList.Add(new Book("Book1", "Author1", "Book"));
            bookList.Add(new Novel("Book2", "Author2", "Novel"));
            bookList.Add(new Journal("Book3", "Author3", "Journal"));
            bookList.Add(new ShortStory("Book4", "Author4", "Short Story"));
            bool isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning)
            {


                Console.Write("\n\n\t\tWelcome to the library!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t[1] Register a new book");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t[2] View a list of the books");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t[3] Search through the library database");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t[4] End program");
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\tChoose: ");

                int Choice;
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Choice);


                switch (Choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        CreateBook();

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        GetBookList();
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        SearchBook();

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tThis program will now close.");
                        Thread.Sleep(1500);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        isRunning = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tAn error occurred, but you can try again.");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always easier for people in the www to read english variable/class/etc names. That dramatically increases the readability of your code for non-yourlanguage-speakers. And it's easier for us to answer.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica thanks for the reply. I have updated the code to be entirely in english now.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through your list and see if anything matches your desired condition:

```
public static void SökBok()
{
    string searchItems = "";

    do
    {
        Console.Write("\n\n\t\tSök igenom biblioteket: ");
        searchItems = Console.ReadLine(); 
        if (searchItems == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tSökfältet kan inte vara tomt. Försök igen!\n");
        }
    } while (searchItems == "");

    // this is what I added
    // for each bok in list
    foreach(var bok in bokLista){

        // if bok text matches searchItems
        //if(bok.Text() == searchItems) {   // commented out exact match, to get similar matches using Contains
        if(bok.Text().ToLower().Contains(searchItems.ToLower())) {

            Console.WriteLine("Found bok: " + bok.ToString());
        }
    }
    // end
}
```

There are other ways to iterate through a list if you wish to learn more. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) is some documentation from Microsoft explaining collection (list) iteration.

It looks like you went an updated your code to more closely match my suggestion. At this point though it seems your look will not always work right because you are going to loop over every book and reset your `found` `bool`. Instead, once you actually find the book, you can break the for-loop (so it will stop running, no need to look at the rest of the books).

Following up on your rendition of the for-loop, here is my suggestion:

```
            // this is what I added
            // for each bok in list
            foreach (var bok in bookList)
            {

                // if bok text matches searchItems
                //if(bok.Text() == searchItems) {   // commented out exact match, to get similar matches using Contains
                if (bok.Text().ToLower().Contains(searchItems.ToLower()))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Beyond this, you'll have to update the question with what your results are and what you are actually expecting, and where it is failing to meet your expectations.

If you would want to compare `book` values other than the `book.Text()` value (which is just its Section it is found in), you would want to replace:

```
if (bok.Text().ToLower().Contains(searchItems.ToLower()))
```

with

```
if (bok.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchItems.ToLower()))
```

This is because you have overridden the `ToString` method to print out all of the information for the book. So if you search that string, you will be searching all possible strings from each book.

Comment: Using == for searching inside text seems less useful than using .Contains that would help getting partial match.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit to include that.

Comment: @Martheen and ibrennan208 -
I appreciate the help, but never managed to make it work. Perhaps it would work if every item in the list was just one word? In this case, the list is full of data from either the the Bok class or any of the underclasses that inherit from Bok. Also translated the code above per request.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 If you have a look at line 176, you can see that there is an entry to the booklist with a name, author and booktype. 

When I search for the booktype using your suggestions I just keep being told it does not exist.


`bookList.Add(new Book("Book1", "Author1", "Book"));`  

I have used an if, else statement to get console writeline to shoot back the appropriate message in accordance with the bool value 'found', but even if I search for something manually entered into the list - it returns as not there.

Comment: This was because it was comparing your search text to `book.Text()` which only includes the section it is found in. I've updated my answer to explain how to search against all the information contained in each book.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 thats brilliant. I didn't catch that. Now I understand what I was comparing it to. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help you! Hopefully it is all working now. If my answer solved it, be sure to mark it as the selected answer to help others know it has already been answered.